# dyld: Symbol not found _PyBaseObject_Type when running C++ project with VTK

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk, premake

I am currently working on setting up VTK to work in my project and I've gotten to the point where I can compile and link successfully, but upon running my application I get:

```
~/Projects/myProj $ ./MyProjDebug
dyld: Symbol not found: _PyBaseObject_Type
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/vtk/lib/libvtkWrappingPython27Core-8.1.1.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/opt/vtk/lib/libvtkWrappingPython27Core-8.1.1.dylib
abort trap: 6
```

VTK was installed from brew and I'm using premake to generate the make files (which can be found here: https://pastebin.com/0dpUUCDS). This next section is from my `premake5.lua` and is how I am currently linking in the VTK library:

```
--------------------------------
-- Find external libs (vtk) --
--------------------------------
local vtkIncPath = os.getenv("VTK_INCLUDE")
local vtkDirPath = os.getenv("VTK_DIR")

if (vtkIncPath) then
   includedirs{vtkIncPath}
else
   error("Missing vtk headers.  Please ensure the headers installed in your include path.")
end
-- Do not use the system vtk directory
if (vtkDirPath) then    
   -- link all libraries manually
   function recursiveLibraries(path)
      linkoptions { "-L"..path}
      for file in lfs.dir(path) do
         if lfs.attributes(path..file, "mode") == "file" then
            local fileName = string.match(file, [[lib(.+).dylib]])
            if fileName == nil then fileName = string.match(file, [[lib(.+).a]]) end
            if fileName == nil then fileName = string.match(file, [[(.+).so]]) end
            if fileName == nil then
            else
               links{fileName}
            end
         elseif lfs.attributes(path..file, "mode") == "directory" then
            recursiveLibraries(path..file)
         end
      end
   end

   recursiveLibraries(vtkDirPath.."/lib/")
end
```

Did I miss any libraries? What am I missing here? What is `cmake` doing that I am not?

Edit: I have updated the function to also link in all `.a` and `.so` files.

Edit2: I don't know if it matters, but I also have python installed through brew.

Comment: If it's going to be a fully C++ project, can you try removing all libraries that include the word `Python` from the link libraries list?

Comment: That is definitely a good option. What I ended up doing was reinstalling without python at all. Your way is probably better though.